# How to get lab streaming layer to work in C#?

Tags: c#, shared-libraries, streaming, data-science, badimageformatexception

I have a device that records live data like eeg measurements. I want to send these data with a lab streaming layer (lsl). Unfortunately I'm unable to configure the lsl and get it to run. I'm not sure if I even copied the dll to the right places.

What I did so far:

- downloaded recent lsl dll from [latest release page](https://github.com/sccn/liblsl/releases/tag/1.13.1)
- copied the liblsl64.lib and liblsl64.dll to my project folder and the Debug folder of my project
- copied LSL.cs (from [github](https://github.com/labstreaminglayer/liblsl-Csharp/blob/master/LSL.cs) as described in [C# Bindings](https://github.com/labstreaminglayer/liblsl-Csharp)) into my project: renamed const string libname = "lsl"; to const string libname = "liblsl64";
- when I run the code:

  liblsl.StreamInfo info = new liblsl.StreamInfo("TestCSharp","EEG");

I get a System.BadImageFormatException: HRESULT: 0x8007000B

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the System.BadImageFormatException, because I have "Any CPU" instead of "x64" in my configurations manager. It also works when using a .Net Core application for accessing the library.